# Finding Professional Genealogist in Germany knowedgeable on Kaiser Wilhelm?

Tags: research-methods, germany, prussia

I would like to find a Professional Genealogist to:

- work with all the time and so that when I make a trip to Germany in a couple of months time I have places to see and points of interest
- to help me in Germany to start the process of finding my ancestry (and current family) to know where my family originated.

Can anyone advise me about how to find such a Professional Genealogist?

As background, my 3rd great grandfather was Kaiser Wilhelm.  My grandmother told me that during World War 2 she was just a little girl and she was put on a boat and went to the United States. My grandmother also told me that she had a charge nurse and a nanny, and that her biological mother had Down Syndrome. Her mother also got sent away but later no one heard from her. My grandmother had jewellery specifically a certain ring.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] because this site works differently to bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites that you may be used to.  To get help here we will need you to use the **edit** button beneath your question to be much more specific about what it is you want to try and learn.

Comment: Are you looking for a professional? These questions are similar: [How can I find a professional genealogist to perform a search in Italy?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/4101/1006) and [How to Trace Ancestors to Switzerland](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2334/1006) and some of the basic principles about choosing a professional found in the answers will also apply to finding a professional who specializes in Prussia.  If you want community members to help you with your research, then please ask a specific question -- "I want to do more research" is too broad.

Comment: With your grandmother being a little girl during World War 2 she will have been born less than 100 years ago and so you need to be aware of our privacy policy in our [help/on-topic]. Are you perhaps trying to be certain that she does descend from Kaiser Wilhelm?  If so, then including the name and birth details of one of her parents (but not her), as long as they were born more than 100 years ago, into your question would seem likely to make that easy.

Comment: Kaiser Wilhelm II had 7 children - for a summary of some of those descendants, including some Americans check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_II,_German_Emperor#First_marriage_and_issue

Comment: @Brandi Baska - What kind of help are your hoping to get on your trip to Germany? The German royal family is documented pretty thoroughly for many generations (Almanach de Gotha). Are you also researching other lines or just wanting to visit places associated with your family or ... ?

Comment: I am wanting to visit places, and just look at family tree... i am getting my DNA report.that is going back 95 links. They the lab has told me that they may be able to pin point a city we  may originated. . My grandmother told me that during WW2 she was just a little girl and she was put on a boat and got to the United States . My grandmother also told me that she had a charge nurse and a nanny.  And that her biological mother had down syndrome  and  but her mother also got sent away but later no one heard from her.. my grandmother had jewlery specifically  a certain  ring... i personally  did

Comment: I understand that you want someone to talk to, but "someone" is still too broad.  Are you looking for peers who have taken trips to Prussia and can talk to you about their experiences, or are you looking for professionals who can take a more active role in helping you plan your trip, or both?  Please clarify what you want.  We can't give you good recommendations of other places you can talk with people without understanding what kind of conversation you want.  Have you considered asking if your local genealogy society has a German special interest group (SIG)?

Comment: Yes i wanna to find a professional  Genealogists while  im in Germany  to help me start the process of  finding ansistory and current family to know where my family truly. Originated.

Comment: Or find a professional Genealogists to work with all the time and so when i make the trip i have places to see points of interest

Comment: I have performed some tidy up of comments on this question so that it stays within the [Be nice](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy.  I've tried to make your question clearer based on your comments here.  Please do not hesitate to use the **edit** button to revise it further if what I have paraphrased does not represent your intentions.

Comment: I didnt know had to be so proper and punctuated . Sorry....

Answer (score 1):

The *Verband deutschsprachiger Berufsgenealogen* is an association of professional genealogists, see [their member list](http://www.berufsgenealogie.net/german/mitglieder-1.html). With the [search query *Berufsgenealoge*](https://www.google.de/search?q=berufsgenealoge) (= professional genealogist) you'll find more using Google.

Some have advanced knowledge on German-American ancestry, so check their profiles and geographic/thematic areas.

Comment: @BrandiBaska If my answer helped you, please think about upvoting it or marking it as accepted. See our tour (http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour)