# Finding parents of Jacob Drager (b. 1825, Germany; living Michigan, USA 1900)?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, germany, vital-records, michigan

Does anyone have any information on the parents of Jacob Drager?

Some of his information is below.

Birth: June of 1825
Birth Place: Germany

Wife: Gustina Rosomfsha
Marriage: About 1867 in Wayne, Michigan

Children: Adelia Drager-born 1862
Anthony Joseph Drager-born 1865

Death: 1903

---

Sources:

- "United States Census, 1900," index and images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M914-B1X : accessed 27 April 2015), Jacob Drager, Dearborn township Dearborn village, Wayne, Michigan, United States; citing sheet 3B, family 70, NARA microfilm publication T623 (Washington, D.C.: National Archives and Records Administration, n.d.); FHL microfilm 1,240,754.
- Michigan Marriages 1822-1995

Comment: I suppose it’s *Dräger*, a far more common name.

Comment: Please also see [Help tracing ancestor back to germany](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/248/help-tracing-ancestor-back-to-germany)