# Identifying ancestor believed to have been born ca 1830 in New Mexico, USA?

Tags: 19th-century, research-methods, new-mexico

The best candidate for my 3rd great grandfather Juan Jose Garcia appears to have:

- been born in the New Mexico Territory in 1830
- been married to either Juana Ma Garcia or Maria Juana Garcia (thought to be same person)
- had two children:

  - Marcos Garcia (my 2nd great grandfather)
  - Antonia Garcia

I cannot confirm that Juan Jose Garcia is the correct name, that's the name that was found by my relatives over 10 years ago and it is where the line has stopped since. We don't have parents names, but we know this person, Juan if that name is correct, had at least two children Marcos Garcia, who is my great great grandfather, and Antonia Garcia who until recently was unknown to us. The only official record I can find to corroborate this is a census record from 1880 [here](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MFDV-JM7) but unfortunately this record only confirms the Mother's name.

My real problem is finding Juan Jose Garcia's Parents. I need to confirm that this is his name so I can make sure I'm searching correctly. But even if I do confirm that, how can I find parents with nothing to go on but an approximate year of birth and a name as common as Juan Jose Garcia?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  In your question you say that your 3rd great grandfather's name cannot be confirmed, so I am wondering what evidence you have for his birth year and location?  I suspect that you may be better working on more of a timeline for your 2nd great grandfather Marcos Garcia first.  By doing that you are likely to have a firmer foundation from which to work on who else was in his immediate family.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo. I think you are right. I've already begun my search in that direction. I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a brief list of the source material you have found so far for all the information in your question?  Reviewing what you have (as well as making a timeline) often alerts you to research avenues you have missed -- plus it allows us a better look at what you have done so far.  I'd also like to encourage you to look at some of the other Q/As on the site like [How can I determine what records are available in a particular locale?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3625/how-can-i-determine-what-records-are-available-in-a-particular-locale/3806#3806).

Comment: I recommend following the advice provided by @JanMurphy.  For me to turn my comment into an answer seems premature, and might mean that you miss out on learning how much more you can find out about your family's history via our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Even though it is talking about a different location, this answer may also be useful: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/249/1006

Comment: I've taken the liberty of starting a timeline within your question.  It can be used to explore and flesh out more details of the evidence you have for each statement in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you say that your 3rd great grandfather's name cannot be confirmed, so I am assuming that you have no strong evidence for his birth year and location.

I suspect that you may be better working on more of a timeline for your 2nd great grandfather Marcos Garcia first.

By doing that you are likely to have a firmer foundation from which to work on who else was in his immediate family.