# Learning family background of Ferdinand Robert Milks who died after 1960 in Frankfurt?

Tags: germany, death-records, hesse

Ferdinand Robert Milk. My grandfather died sometime in 1960 plus. He lived in Frankfurt and died there.

I would like to know his family background.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Depending on his age and date of death, your grandfather may be on the wrong side of our privacy policy at [help/on-topic].  Are you able to [edit] your question to include when he was born, please?  As long as that is more than 100 years ago we can discuss his details freely here.

Comment: I also encourage you to read the [help] and try to improve your question -- as it is, your question is far too broad.  "if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format".  The question is also a possible duplicate of [Tracing Ancestors Back to Germany](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/248/1006).  That question and others tagged Germany may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean Frankfurt am Main, the [Personenstandsarchiv Hessen](http://wiki-de.genealogy.net/Personenstandsarchiv_Hessen) should help you. You can search their registers for death records online ([Hessische Geburten-, Ehe-, Sterberegister](http://www.lagis-hessen.de/de/subjects/gsform/sn/hadis)). However, I found online registers for Frankfurt just until 1959. Contact them and ask for later years, they should have all of the city’s death records older than 30 years. It might be helpful to narrow down the possible time of death first. The death record should contain the birth place, the birth record number and the parents or your grandfather.