# Is there an online site where all Prussian and German Census can be found?

Tags: germany, census-records, prussia

Like a bad beginner I had come across one census taken of the town called Angloh Germany in the Kirchham area in Passau region I believe. Anyway I long lost that link. I was hoping to see what family names and resided there that may have been my original ancestors. Ones that became Angloher.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a listing of the census records that are available online in the FamilySearch Wiki article [Germany Census](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Germany_Census).

The definitive work on German Census records is Roger Minert's book *German census records 1816-1916 : the when, where, and how of a valuable genealogical resource*. You can find more information and locate a copy using the links below.

- [Family History Library](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/2690879?availability=Family%20History%20Library) catalog entry
- [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/german-census-records-1816-1916-the-when-where-and-how-of-a-valuable-genealogical-resource/oclc/952052535) catalog entry (use this to find in a library near you)
- [Family Roots Publishing](https://www.familyrootspublishing.com/store/product_view.php?id=3145&title=German%20Census%20Records,%201816-1916:%20The%20When,%20Where,%20and%20How%20of%20a%20Valuable%20Genealogical%20Resource%20-%20hardbound) book details & ordering information at the publisher's website

To make use of these references, you'll want to confirm the location. I looked up "Angloh" in the online [Meyers Gazetteer](https://www.meyersgaz.org/) and got one result for a farm name (not a town)  associated with [Kircham](https://www.meyersgaz.org/place/10966034) (the Bezirkskommando for Kirchham is in Passau).

Understanding the place and the surrounding jurisdictions is important if you want to do a place search in the FamilySearch catalog.  It helps to know what records were created and where and for what purpose -- knowing this is crucial if you need to find out where the records might be held now, if they are not online.

For example: Kircham is listed in the online MeyersGaz as "Kirchham, Griesbach, Niederbayern, Bayern". To do a place search in the FamilySearch catalog, you'll need to reverse the jurisdictions to go from the largest to the smallest and search for:

- Germany
- Germany, Bayern
- Germany, Bayern, Niederbayern

Use the information on the Detail page of Meyers Gazetteer to inform your place and keyword searches in the catalog.  The details tell you where to look to find various types of records.  The only census I was able to find with a quick search was under Niederbayern and the films showed the camera icon with a key, which usually means they are only available to view at a Family History Center.  I would be surprised to find these records online as German privacy laws can be very strict.

It might be time for you to do a review of your prior research to see where you found the information that sent you looking for that census record in Angloh long ago.  See the question [Tracing Ancestor Back To Germany](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/248/1006).  GeneJ's advice in [this answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/249/1006) to avoid **premature connectivitis syndrome (PCS)** is wise:

> Work from a time line on which you specify locations (and/or events).
>   Pick the point on the timeline where you feel you have solid
>   information; begin there. When you move from that point in time, think
>   INCHWORM (rather than leapfrog).

Resources:

- FamilySearch Wiki Article: [Tracing Immigrant Origins](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Tracing_Immigrant_Origins)
- Joe Beine's [German Roots](https://www.germanroots.com/): Resources for German Genealogy on the Internet
- Guest Post at *Genealogy Gems*: [German Census Records](https://lisalouisecooke.com/2018/02/12/german-census-records/) by James M. Beidler
- YouTube: [Step-By-Step Guide to MeyersGaz.org for German Genealogy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2aLSvE_upY) by James M. Beidler

Comment: "Bezirkskommando" sounds unusual to me. Did you mean "Bezirksamt" like the administration of a district? In Germany Bezirk would rather be called Kreis I think. [Just saw that you cited that from Meyers Gazetteer.]

Comment: @nebulon42 That was copied directly from the Online MeyersGaz detail page for Kirchham: "BKdo Passau - The Bezirkskommando for Kirchham is in Passau. The Bezirkskommando is the District Military Command. You can look in the BKdo to find military records."  Perhaps language usage has changed in German since MeyersGaz was published (1912)?